# Mark property as deprecated in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

How can I mark a @property in Objective C as deprecated?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Unless you really want to deprecate based on iOS version, which I suspect you don't want to do, you can use `DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE`

```
@property (strong) NSObject *object DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;
```

Comment: Is there a way you can add a message to tell the user what property they should be using instead?

Comment: @fatuhoku Use `DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(message)`.

Answer (score 15):

from `NSObjCRuntime.h`

```
#define NS_AVAILABLE(_mac, _ios)
#define NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(_mac)
#define NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(_ios)
#define NS_DEPRECATED(_macIntro, _macDep, _iosIntro, _iosDep)
#define NS_DEPRECATED_MAC(_macIntro, _macDep)
#define NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(_iosIntro, _iosDep)
```

you can use these macros

this is one example in `UITableViewCell.h`

```
@property(nonatomic,copy)   NSString *text NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 3_0);                        // default is nil
```

Comment: Use `DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE` from `AvailabilityMacros.h` if it doesn't depend on the iOS version

Answer (score 9):

You can also use DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE("Use anotherProperty instead.") and provide a meaningful message hinting the user what to use in place of the deprecated property. 
Xcode will show a warning when the property is used.

example:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *someProperty DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE("Use anotherProperty instead.");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can type macro like this below one in .pch to be gloabl for all the app

```
    #define DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE     __attribute__((deprecated))
```

in mark the method as following example

```
    -(void) exmapleMethodName DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE{
          // code
    }
```